# TCPconnection: server doesn't 'understand' that receiving is over

Tags: c, sockets, serversocket, recv

I'm dealing with a problem on the tcp connection I'm building. When, sending datas from client to server, the server seems to "wait"(not so obvious to me why) for another 'recv()' and the client never exits, as it has finished the sending part and waits to 'recv()' an answer from the server. That comes to a kind of deadlock.

The following code is the part where,I think,the problem is.

**Server code**:

```
  #define BUFFSIZE 1024;
  char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
  /*...*/
  bzero(buffer,BUFFSIZE);
  while(received > 0) {     /* indicates end of connection */   

      /* recv: Check for more data coming from client*/
          printf("before recv\n");
      if( (received = recv(sock,buffer,BUFFSIZE-1,0) ) < 0){
        perror("Failed to recv bytes from client");
        exit(1);
      } 
      printf("received %d bytes \n", received); 
      sum_bytes += received;

      printf("after recv\n");
      if( strstr(buffer,"End")) {
        printf("strstr: %s\n",buffer);
        break;
      }               
      bzero(buffer,BUFFSIZE);
}
printf("\ntotal bytes received are %d \n", sum_bytes);
```

**Client Code**:

```
for(i=0; i<num_packets; i++){          

          /* Send the packet to the server */
          char packet[packet_size];
          bzero(packet,packet_size);
          if( (sent = send(sockfd,packet,packet_size,0)) != packet_size){
              perror("Client: send() sent a diff num of bytes than expected");
              exit(1);
          }       
          bytes += sent;
    }
    /* send another final packet("End")in order to inform server that sending is over */
    if( (sent = send(sockfd,"End",3, 0)) != 3) {
          perror("Client:send() sent a diff num of bytes than expected");
    }
    bytes += sent;
    printf("total bytes sent are %d \n", bytes);
```

}

As you can observe, I don't mind about the sending datas but only about the packet sizes.
This code **works** perfect **for 1 packet sending**... but not for more! :/
if there are more packets than one to be sent, then the client "blocks" (needs ^C to exit) and the server stops on the beginning of the loop, after he has received all the datas (he does one more loop!).

One more query that I have is that the same exact code works fine if I use 'sizeof(BUFFSIZE)' instead of 'BUFFSIZE'. And I am wondering why... :/ Any ideas?

e.g ./client:

> ```
> END
> total bytes sent are 1034 
> /* press ^C */
> ```

./server:

> before recv
>   received 358 bytes
>   after recv
>   before recv
>   received 676 bytes
>    after recv
>   bef recv    /* stucks here*/
>
> (...the following comes when i press ctr-c on client...)
>   received 0 bytes
>   after recv
>
> total bytes received are 1034      /** right amount of bytes received!! **/

Comment: Could you post the corrected code excerpts as an answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED!!:**

I send data packets with so many datas as the packet-size! Before, I sended for example "abcde" with packet-size=1024. With using memset in the client, problem solved! 
Thanks for helping!

Correct code (altered only in client):

```
for(i=0; i<num_packets; i++){          
          /* Send the packet to the server */
          char packet[packet_size];
          memset(packet,'-',packet_size);
          if( (sent = send(sockfd,packet,packet_size,0)) != packet_size){
              perror("Client: send() sent a different number of bytes than expected");
              exit(1);
          }       
          bytes += sent;
    }
```

Comment: What does the `memset()` have to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using TCP, there's no guarantee that the number of bytes you `send` on one side will equal the amount you `recv` on the other side.  They could be split up, or joined together.
For example, if you sent "ab" and then "cd" you could receive "ab" then "cd", or "a" then "bcd", or "abcd", or "abc" then "d", and so forth.

Since `strstr` stops searching its first argument when it finds a NUL byte, and you're sending NUL bytes with your client, it's likely the last `recv` is putting something like "\0\0\0End" in your buffer, so `strstr` considers it a zero-length string and doesn't find the "End" substring.

Comment: Nice Tip! Thanks! But what do you suggest? I tried it without 'bzero()' at the end...but it still doesn't work properly.

Comment: You could create a function like strstr that searches memory.  You'd have to pass the size of the buffer and target sequence in.  But on second thought, I don't think this is the solution either.  There's some detail we're not thinking of.

Comment: Is there a chance that even the datas of "End" packet will be received in different order? (eg. "nEd") Or just the packets are being received differently? I am curious if there is any alternative way to solve it! Even without using "End" packet! :/

Comment: No, TCP [guarantees](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793#section-1.5) that each byte will be received in order, without any missing or duplicate bytes, or it is an error.  I don't think you need the "End" packet at all personally; when `recv` returns zero, the client has finished.

Comment: I tried it without the "End" packet...and again it blocks! Don't know why either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the sending socket when you are done with it.  Until you close (with `close` or `shutdown`) the socket, recv will not return zero.

Comment: I see your point,but that's not the all code. close() is on the end of the client's code I posted. But even if that was true, why would then it works for one packet sending? :/

Comment: `send(sockfd,"End",packet_size, 0)) != packet_size)` should probably be `send(sockfd,"End",3, 0)) != 3)`, but that's probably not the cause of what you're seeing.  Could you put all of the client and server cod e up?

Comment: well,I put that 'cause I want a certain packet's size distribution. That's not a prob,imo! Do you see anything wrong with the buffer?